# How to remove index meta tag <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">

Tags: plugins, seo

I need to remove this line  `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">` on my site for the accessibility mode.

I successfully added the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">` 
by calling add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_no_robots', 1); but it shows both metatags

```
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"> <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

I didn't find the way to remove the index metatag line.

Comment: You've tagged this question with `plugin-all-in-one-seo` - are you using the plugin?

Comment: Nope, I do not use any plugin for <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">. But I am using a custom plugin for enabling/disabling to the accessibility mode where I simply adding these lines add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_no_robots', 1);  I kept looking the way to remove the robots metatag. even through I tried this statement remove_action( 'wp_head', 'robots'); but no luck so far.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I can't help you with that as I'm unfamiliar with the core robots stuff. Somebody else will probably pick it up - just wanted to make sure it is about WP core and not a plugin.

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/19/robots-api-and-max-image-preview-directive-in-wordpress-5-7/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_no_robots', 1 );
```

Try using

```
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_no_robots' );
```

In your code you are actually trying to  add one more function call to  pre called function rather than just changing its  value to noindex. Use add_filter instead. :)